# How to model friend relationship in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a People model that I want to allow un-directed relationships on (Friend, Family, Neighbor, etc.)  When you mark one person as being the friend of another then they both are friends of each other.

```
Class People
  id
  name

Class Relationship
  id
  person_a_id
  person_b_id
  relationship_type
```

Now, assuming we have some People data (record ids = 1,2,3,4,5) this is how the Relationship table might look:

```
id  person_a_id  person_b_id  relationship_type
--  -----------  -----------  --------------------
 1     1            2           friend
 2     1            3           neighbor
```

What this tells me is that Person 1 has a friend (Person 2) and a neighbor (Person 3).  It also tells me that Person 2 has a friend (Person 1) and Person 3 has a neighbor (Person 1).

I think I could do this with some [Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) but I'm thinking that there is a cleaner way.  Am I missing something and there is a Gem out there, waiting to fulfill my every need (at least as far as this question goes)?  Or do I have to write one...

Answer (score 5):

Self-referential associations are the way to go here.

The best resource on the topic, in my opinion, is this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

User model (Person for you):

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

Friendship model (Relationship for you):

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: A self-referential `has_many :through` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: so my total friends is inverse_friends + friends ?